# Meta Tag Proposal: Site analysis

Tags: feature-request

A number of threads on the meta have popped up providing some insight on the users of the site.

The ones that come to mind are:

1.[Ranking of votes by reputation among top (+1k) users](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/ranking-of-votes-by-reputation-among-top-1k-users)
2.[August 2017: Regression between reputation rank and log reputation](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/august-2017-regression-between-reputation-rank-and-log-reputation)
3.[December 2015: Regression between reputation rank and log reputation on Econ.SE](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/december-2015-regression-between-reputation-rank-and-log-reputation-on-econ-se)

Though I don't know if there are practical ramification for site policy, I think it would be a good idea to create a tag [site-analysis](/questions/tagged/site-analysis) just to put them all together.

a description of the tag can be.

> an original analysis of site data using database or statistical methods.

If anyone has  a better description or comments on the idea let me know.